# How to force meson to use only wrap subproject

Tags: meson-build

I have a few subprojects defined in wrap files in the subprojects directory and declared in the meson.build file. Unfortunately I am forced to have some of the subprojects installed on my host system. Meson by default checks if a subproject is installed in the host os filesystem then eventually downloads and builds the subproject if it is unavailable. How to force meson to not use system libraries/headers but to always download/build subprojects independently in own build directory and link it during compilation?

subprojects/xyz.wrap:

```
[wrap-git]
url = https://github.com/bar/xyz.git
revision = HEAD

[provide]
xyz = xyz_dep
```

meson.build:

```
xyz = dependency('xyz')
...
deps = [
    ...
    xyz
    ...
]
executable(foo, dependencies: deps)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force a dependency to fallback to its local subprojects version using `--force-fallback-for=<dependency_name>` during `meson setup ...`.

For example, I have SDL2 installed as a system package, but I can use the WrapDB version with the following command:

```bash
meson setup build --force-fallback-for=sdl2
```

Reference:

- https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/7218

Answer (score 1):

The `force-fallback` option that @joshua-taylor-eppinette suggested is the correct option if you are building a meson project that someone else wrote.

If this is your own meson project (which seems to be the case), a better approach would be to not use `dependency('xyz')`, as by definition `dependency` will look in your installed system packages before falling back to a subproject.

If you want to *always* use the subproject dependency instead of a system package, replace `dependency('xyz')` with [subproject.get_variable](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual_returned_subproject.html#subprojectget_variable):

```
subproject('xyz').get_variable('xyz_dep')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also force fallback of all dependencies with `-Dwrap_mode=forcefallback`.

See meson options : https://mesonbuild.com/Builtin-options.html#core-options